# Bootstrap login window validation fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to Bootstrap and I wrote code to login window. It just load the popup window. But validation fails to fire.
Please correct me where it goes wrong. Console shows error message says Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Vertical Form Layout</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
        </script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the reference to `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.1/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js`

The call to `$('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator` requires the above reference.